# How to offer Remove Ads (IAP) in a Sprite Kit App?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

I have a problem finding the right way to offer IAP in my app, developed in SpriteKit, for removing ads. I only saw tutorials about how it´s done in regular swift language. 
Does someone know how to apply this kind of IAP to a SpriteKit App or where to find examples?

Comment: There are zillions of ways.  Be specific about what you are stuck with showing work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement IAP for removing ads in SpriteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395515/how-to-implement-iap-for-removing-ads-in-spritekit)